# Microsoft Fabric components and data replication

Tags: azure-synapse, fabric, onelake

I understand the OneLake should ensure a single copy of data.

So, when we use Azure Synapse Data Warehouse and aggregate data into new tables, does that create a new dataset on OneLake (in a new workspace / directory / location) or does the new aggregate data reside in Synapse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you crate a Lakehouse or Warehouse in Fabric, the service will create a folder structure under the top onelake folder like that: *worksapce_name/Lakehouse_name/table_name*

Please note that although Fabric uses the name Synapse Data engineering, It has nothing to do with the Synapse analytics service and is a new service altogether.